# Switching to su if you have no password

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

```
Ubuntu 22.04
```

Logged in as the ubuntu user, using an ssh key, I did:

```
sudo su

adduser test --disabled-password
sudo su deploy
```

So now, test is in the sudo group, and it has no password.

I added the key to the /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys, then I logged back on as the test user.

I tried doing:

```
sudo su
```

But it's asking me for a password.

What do I need to do, so I can switch the test account to su mode?

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu it asked you for a user and a password. This serves as the admin password for sudo. I have Ubuntu 22.04 running here. How did you set up your Ubuntu machine?  OR, are you a standard user and some other person / organization set it up?

Comment: I am afraid w/o password you can't use `sudo`. Try with `ssh test@host` with the proper `ssh` key

Comment: Here's what I stated in my question:

Logged in as the ubuntu user, using an ssh key, I did...

I added the key to the /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys, then I logged back on as the test user.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add the following to the sudoers file:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Which will give everyone in the sudo group sudo power, without having to enter a password.